# email a video in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, email, video

I have an app that records a video and saves it straight to the photo library on the iPhone. I want to, as soon as the user finishes recording, have the app open up in mail, with the video attached. How should I go about doing this?

I am using this basic idea: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-in-app-email/

How do I get the file path for the video?

Answer (score 0):

You could either store the video in your app and then attach that into the email before copying it to the photo library or show the user their photo library in the app via UIImagePicker -  This may help or just google it ...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135

Comment: The image picker will return the UIIMage which you can then compress and attach to the email.